# Querying MS-SQL database from PHP using [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server] gets error when trying a WHERE with a Binary Column

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, unixodbc

I have a Database on MS-SQL Server. There is a table with a column contact_uuid(PK, FK, Binary(16), not null).
I am using PHP 7.3 with odbc to perform a SELECT from that table using binary INDEX.

```
$sql="SELECT  * FROM mdb.dbo.ca_contact WHERE contact_uuid = convert(binary, 0x".$uuid.");";
$connection = getConnectionMSSQL('BD');
odbc_do($connection, 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON');
$query = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
odbc_fetch_row($query,0);
    if(($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) != false)
        {
            while($row = odbc_fetch_array($query))
            $salida[] = $row;
        }
    else $salida[]="Fallo la consulta: $sql<br>: ".odbc_error();   
print_r($salida);
```

If I use the script I get:

> Fallo la consulta: SELECT * FROM mdb.dbo.ca_contact WHERE contact_uuid
>   = convert(binary, 0x3674B515FFE11C4F85BF48A4B1BC29F2);

If I use the output directly on SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO I get the proper resulset.

Comment: Slight detour...but a critical one...you need to parameterize your queries before [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) comes to visit.

Comment: (1) "If [you] use the output directly..."  Does that mean, "if you execute the query directly"? i.e., can you execute `SELECT * FROM mdb.dbo.ca_contact WHERE contact_uuid = convert(binary, 0x3674B515FFE11C4F85BF48A4B1BC29F2);` through Management Studio? (2) DO you get any additional error message? An ODBC Trace is likely to provide more info, in any case.

Comment: Hi TallTedd thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi TallTedd thanks for the answer.                                                                             (1) I use to echo $sql in PHP to validate que executed query. So Yes  I can execute the query. And (2) There are no error message. Just Fails!.